# Failure: Inconsistent type in JSPB repeated field array. Got undefined expected object

Tags: protocol-buffers, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
Inconsistent type in JSPB repeated field array. Got undefined expected object +AssertionError: Failure: Inconsistent type in JSPB repeated field array. Got undefined expected object
```

I am using fabric, and I think this is a problem with the chain code, but can't point the problem.

here is the stacktrace:

```
Fri, 29 Apr 2022 13:12:24 GMT + Failure: Inconsistent type in JSPB repeated field array. Got undefined expected object +AssertionError: Failure: Inconsistent type in JSPB repeated field array. Got undefined expected object
    at new goog.asserts.AssertionError (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:87:1065)
    at Object.goog.asserts.fail (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:90:89)
    at /Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:502:168
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:101:188)
    at Function.jspb.Message.assertConsistentTypes_ (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:502:114)
    at Function.jspb.Message.bytesListAsU8 (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:501:217)
    at proto.protos.ChaincodeInput.getArgsList_asU8 (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/protos/peer/chaincode_pb.js:557:59)
    at proto.protos.ChaincodeInput.serializeBinaryToWriter (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/@hyperledger/fabric-gateway/dist/protos/peer/chaincode_pb.js:508:15)
    at jspb.BinaryWriter.writeMessage (/Users/user/hl-f/backend/node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:451:479)+
```

the code that do this is a simple AddAsset query that i modified,

```js
@Transaction()
    public async AddAsset(ctx: Context, assetid : string,email: string,phone :string,address :string): Promise<void> {
        const exists = await this.AssetExists(ctx, assetid);
        if (exists) {
            throw new Error(`The asset ${assetid} already exists`);
        }

        const asset = {
            AssetID: assetid,
           
            Email: email,
            Phone: phone,
            Address: address,
            

        };
        await ctx.stub.putState(assetid, Buffer.from(stringify(sortKeysRecursive(asset))));
    }
```

Comment: Actually the problem could be client side, ie your code around trying to submit the transaction

Comment: Thanks, I found out the problem, my backend gateway, was causing the problem, the JSON file I was receiving is not the same I sent, the problem was with JSON not having the exact value

Answer (score 0):

Always double check, triple check your app/backend, when encountering this problem.

you might have a similar problem to this:

```
json = {
Assetid : "123",
...
}

contract.submitTransaction("AddAsset", json.AssetID, ...);
```

explanation:

json.Assetid = 123

while
json.AssetID = undefined

I feel stupid, on how much time i wasted on this bug, thinking it was the chaincode,

And remember double, triple check.
And happy coding.